# Typing an object self-referentially in typescript

Tags: typescript, type-inference, typescript-generics, type-constraints

I have been trying to type a 'configuration object' used to construct an indexed store. I have simplified the case down to its minimum, but hopefully the motivation still makes some sense.

I'm concerned the model is too self-referential to be able to be expressed in typescript, as I keep hitting dead ends trying to define the types. However, I don't know what the next best approach would be that DOES align well with typescript's expressivity.

In particular I can't find a good pattern for defining the type constraints to ensure that functions that consume from some index are typed correctly for the rows emitted by that index.

A valid index-configuration looks like `chainedMap` below. If I can solve my typing problem, then compiler errors should be generated when one of the function arguments doesn't match the return value of the function(s) it is 'chained' from.

```
const chainedMap = { //configures a store for strings
  length: (value: string) => value.length, // defines a 'length' index populated by numbers
  threshold: { // defines a 'threshold' index, derived from length, populated by booleans
    length: (value: number) => value >= 10,
  },
  serialise: { // defines a serialise index, derived from both length and threshold, populated by strings
    length: (value: number) => value.toString(),
    threshold: (value: boolean) => value.toString(),
  },
} as const;
```

Because of the intent to chain indexes together, the argument types of some functions are coupled to the output types of other functions in the same object.

A valid derived index like 'threshold' or 'serialise' must reference only named indexes which actually exist, such as 'length', 'threshold' or 'serialise', and must define a mapping function that consumes the type of data contained in that index e.g. if you consume from 'length' your function should accept numbers, and to consume from 'threshold', your function should accept booleans.

ATTEMPTED TYPINGS

Top-level named FUNCTIONS in the `chainedMap` create the primary indexes. They consume rows as they are added to the store, and they emit rows into their correspondingly-named index. For example, isolating the top level 'length' index it could be typed like this, for a store that takes string rows...

```
const lengthIndex: PrimaryMapping<string, number> = {
  length: (value: string) => value.length,
} as const;
```

Top level OBJECTS in the `chainedMap` configuration are indexes derived *from* indexes. The objects contain named functions which consume rows from their correspondingly named index to generate rows in the derived index. For example, isolating the top level 'threshold' property on its own (which transforms rows from the length index into an index of booleans) it could be typed like this to consume the rows coming from the length index...

```
const lengthThresholdIndex: SecondaryMapping<typeof lengthIndex, boolean> = {
  threshold: {
    length: (value: number) => value >= 10,
  },
} as const;
```

Finally it should be possible to derive an index from a derived index, making it possible to construct arbitrary chains. Isolating a mapping from the 'serialise' index, it might be typed like this...

```
const thresholdSerialisedIndex: SecondaryMapping<
  typeof lengthThresholdIndex,
  string
> = {
  serialise: {
    threshold: (value: boolean) => value.toString(),
  },
} as const;
```

I arrived at these definitions of Primary and Secondary index to be able to construct the config object in a more-or-less type-safe way but with a huge increase in complexity compared to the original simple config object. The type definitions and composition needed to recreate the simple config is shown below...

```
interface PrimaryMapping<In, Out> {
  [indexCreated: string]: (value: In) => Out;
}

interface SecondaryMapping<
  Index extends PrimaryMapping<any, any> | SecondaryMapping<any, any>,
  Out
> {
  [indexCreated: string]: {
    [fromIndex: string]: (
      value: Index extends PrimaryMapping<any, infer In>
        ? In
        : Index extends SecondaryMapping<any, infer In>
        ? In
        : never
    ) => Out;
  };
}

const lengthIndex: PrimaryMapping<string, number> = {
  length: (value: string) => value.length,
} as const;

const lengthThresholdIndex: SecondaryMapping<typeof lengthIndex, boolean> = {
  threshold: {
    length: (value: number) => value >= 10,
  },
} as const;

const lengthSerialisedIndex: SecondaryMapping<typeof lengthIndex, string> = {
  serialise: {
    length: (value: number) => value.toString(),
  },
} as const;

const thresholdSerialisedIndex: SecondaryMapping<
  typeof lengthThresholdIndex,
  string
> = {
  serialise: {
    threshold: (value: boolean) => value.toString(),
  },
} as const;

const index = {
  ...lengthIndex,
  ...lengthThresholdIndex,
  serialise: {
    ...lengthSerialisedIndex.serialise,
    ...thresholdSerialisedIndex.serialise,
  },
} as const;
```

However, I am struggling to find a good way to combine these to benefit from the simplicity of the original, terse configuration object, but with type-checking. To get any typings to work I seem to have to isolate these chains in both typing and declaration which ends up a horrible mess.

Ideally I would have e.g. an Index type which would raise two compiler errors in the broken example below

- `threshold: (value: number) => value.toString()` has a `number` argument, but the threshold index returns `boolean` rows.
- `foo: (value: boolean) => !value` references an index 'foo' which doesn't exist as a top-level property of chainedMap.

```
const chainedMap: Index<string> = {
  length: (value: string) => value.length,
  threshold: {
    length: (value: number) => value >= 10,
    foo: (value: boolean) => !value,
  },
  serialise: {
    length: (value: number) => value.toString(),
    threshold: (value: number) => value.toString(),
  },
} as const;
```

I feel I came close when I was able to define a single Recursive Mapped type that combined elements of both Primary and Secondary like...

```
interface Index<
  In,
  Out,
  I extends Index<any, In, any> | never = never
> {
  [indexName: string]:
    | ((value: In) => Out)
    | {
        [deriveFromName: string]: (
          value: I[typeof deriveFromName] extends (...args: any[]) => infer In
            ? In
            : I[typeof deriveFromName][keyof I[typeof deriveFromName]] extends (
                ...args: any[]
              ) => infer In
            ? In
            : never
        ) => Out;
      };
}
```

...but it would have to be used with a reference to its own type `typeof chainedMap` which is illegal...

```
const chainedMap : Index <string, any, typeof chainedMap> = {
  length: (value: string) => value.length,
  threshold: {
    length: (value: number) => value >= 10,
  },
  serialise: {
    length: (value: number) => value.toString(),
    threshold: (value: boolean) => value.toString(),
  },
} as const;
```

Is it possible to have a self-referential type like this?

Is there an alternative pattern that would enforce the logical integrity of functions in my simply-declared configuration object?

Comment: Thanks for fixing the code fence, @Nishant. I'm disappointed in myself that I missed that in the preview.

Comment: Which function do you consider a top level ?

Comment: The example `chainedMap` configuration object has top-level properties (immediate children) which are EITHER functions OR objects containing functions. In the final implementation, a top-level function like `length` will be notified of every (string) row added to the store, and will populate (number) rows in the length index. Non-top-level functions are properties of the top-level objects. These second-level functions' name the index they will consume to create a derived index. They don't get notified of original rows stored, only rows output to the named index. Their types should correspond.

Comment: I tried to clarify by adding some comment lines to the original `chainedMap`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now have an adequate approach that allows me to progress. It can't infer everything from a simple config object. The approach requires minor 'duplication' of types. However, being explicit in this way could be seen as a virtue.

Valid declarations now look like...

```
const validConfig: Config<
  string,
  { length: number; threshold: boolean; serialise: string }
> = {
  length: (value: string) => value.length,
  threshold: {
    length: (value: number) => value >= 10,
  },
  serialise: {
    length: (value: number) => value.toString(),
    threshold: (value: boolean) => value.toString(),
  },
} as const
```

`Config` explicitly declares generic parameters, one for the type of `Stored` item accepted in the store, and another as an ephemeral `Sample` type (which is never instantiated) to define index names and the type of valid entries in that index.

Validation rules are projected from these two types to enforce
constraints on functions that create direct indexes or derived indexes, correctly generating compile errors for invalid structures.

```
// Function that populates an index by transforming items added to the store, or to other indexes' rows
type IndexFn<RowIn, RowOut> = (value: RowIn) => RowOut;

// A map that populates an index by transforming rows from one or more named indexes
type IndexMap<Sample, RowOut> = Partial<{
  [consumedIndex in keyof Sample]: IndexFn<Sample[consumedIndex], RowOut>;
}>;

// config combining direct indexes (functions that index items added to the store)
// and derived indexes (maps of functions that index other named indexes' rows)
type Config<Stored, Sample> = {
  [IndexName in keyof Sample]:
    | IndexFn<Stored, Sample[IndexName]> // a direct index
    | IndexMap<Sample, any>; // a derived index
};
```

Examples of invalid configs which generate compile errors look like this...

```
const invalidIndexName: Config<
  string,
  { length: number; threshold: boolean; serialise: string }
> = {
  length: (value: string) => value.length,
  threshold: {
    length: (value: number) => value >= 10,
  },
  serialise: {
    length: (value: number) => value.toString(),
    threshold: (value: boolean) => value.toString(),
    // there is no index foo
    foo: (value: number) => value.toString(), 
  },
} as const;

const invalidDirectIndexArg: Config<
  string,
  { length: number; negate: boolean }
> = {
  length: (value: string) => value.length,
  negate: {
    // length is a number not a boolean
    length: (value: boolean) => !value, 
  },
} as const;

const invalidDerivedIndexArg: Config<
  string,
  { length: number; threshold: boolean; serialise: string }
> = {
  length: (value: string) => value.length,
  threshold: {
    length: (value: number) => value >= 10,
  },
  serialise: {
    // threshold is a boolean not a number
    threshold: (value: number) => value.toString(), 
  },
} as const;
```

A slight remaining frustration is that I have functioning 'Extract' types which can correctly infer the Stored and Sample types directly from the config object, but I still can't find a way to avoid declaring the index types. Utility extraction types are demonstrated as follows...

```
/** Utility type that extracts the stored type accepted by direct index functions */
type ExtractStored<C extends Config<any, any>> = {
  [IndexName in keyof C]: C[IndexName] extends IndexFn<infer RowIn, any>
    ? RowIn
    : never;
}[keyof C];

/** Extracts the type emitted by a specific named index, whether direct or derived */
type ExtractRow<
  C extends Config<any, any>,
  IndexName extends keyof C
> = C[IndexName] extends IndexFn<any, infer DirectRowOut>
  ? DirectRowOut
  : C[IndexName] extends IndexMap<any, infer DerivedRowOut>
  ? DerivedRowOut
  : never;

/** Extracts an ephemeral Sample 'object' type mapping all named indexes to the index's row type. */
type ExtractSample<C extends Config<any, any>> = {
  [IndexName in keyof C]: ExtractRow<C, IndexName>;
};

/** Prove extraction of key aspects */

type TryStored = ExtractStored<typeof validConfig>; //correctly extracts string as the input type
type TrySample = ExtractSample<typeof validConfig>; //correctly creates type mapping index names to their types

type LengthType = ExtractRow<typeof validConfig, "length">; //correctly evaluates to number
type ThresholdType = ExtractRow<typeof validConfig, "threshold">; //correctly evaluates to boolean
type SerialiseType = ExtractRow<typeof validConfig, "serialise">; //correctly evaluates to string
```

In the future if anyone can exploit these extracted types to allow e.g. a simple `validate(indexConfig)` call to raise compiler errors without declaring explicit generic Store,Sample inline that would be an improvement.

All of the above examples can be experimented with in the playground at https://tsplay.dev/wXk3QW

Comment: Thanks to @captain-yossarian who added so many ideas to get me here

Answer (score 1):

Please don't treat it as a complete answer. It is a WIP. Just want to clarify.
Consider this exmaple:

```js
const chainedMap = {
    length: (value: string) => value.length,
    threshold: {
        length: (value: number) => value >= 10,
    },
    serialise: {
        length: (value: number) => value.toString(),
        threshold: (value: boolean) => value.toString(),
    },
} as const;

type Fn = (...args: any[]) => any

type TopLevel = Record<string, Fn>

const validation = <
    Keys extends string,
    Props extends Fn | Record<Keys, Fn>,
    Config extends Record<Keys, Props>
>(config: Validate<Config>) => config

type Validate<
    Original extends Record<
        string,
        Fn | Record<string, Fn>
    >,
    Nested = Original, Level = 0> =
    (Level extends 0
        ? {
            [Prop in keyof Nested]:
            Nested[Prop] extends Fn
            ? Nested[Prop]
            : Validate<Original, Nested[Prop], 1>
        }
        : (keyof Nested extends keyof Original
            ? (Nested extends Record<string, Fn>
                ? {
                    [P in keyof Nested]: P extends keyof Original
                    ? (Original[P] extends (...args: any) => infer Return
                        ? (Parameters<Nested[P]>[0] extends Return
                            ? Nested[P]
                            : never)
                        : never)
                    : never
                }
                : never)
            : never)
    )

type Result = Validate<typeof chainedMap>

validation({
    length: (value: string) => value.length,
    threshold: {
        length: (value: number) => value >= 10,
    },
    serialise: {
        length: (value: number) => value.toString(), // ok
    },
})

validation({
    length: (value: string) => value.length,
    threshold: {
        length: (value: number) => value >= 10,
    },
    serialise: {
        length: (value: string) => value.toString(), // error, because top level [length] returns number
    },
})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAjGHsDsGcBcAJQAsCGBLSBTAJgWRQA7wC88A3sPFfADaaQDmsSAXPABQBuKNArpmzgAnDAwCUJAHzxufTADo6jZgBpK1ZkMzQk4GtjYVqx2vSasOs-m0i8AtgCNMQicWlXM8SaQCMABjVjAF9A6mhnNB40cMN1E1NlCy4ea3hbR2dXdxSFWHAAZVgRRnYxUPjNbV19NmS5NgdwPUwUSCyZHPk8wuKGUvL4EOAg+BRoRCg4AG4QWABPAk8AMUgSDnkNlCEGaDZWuYBtAF12-dmFzwAVcAIAGUxOTBo1gCVMCCFsAB5hURV4FaSMCTBCyNDYFCwNBQNZfOLwADSmDm40wAA9YPRsONfowBgAFIQ3VEYrHjFbwAA+8DeH2+SJR-0BAwAwlAAGZoBjwdGYyDYmnvcCfL4M6D-QnEoGSdgQSCchhsABqUQhmK+bPlXMk7TlCvOi3gKpo4MhmDhxgA8iIGBgeDzSfzxrThd94cZcQwBsYKdSXSLPUzIEDjJIBgA5bSY7Bra1cu00f73R7PUh+aTEeHsZNPB18gV+d3UAD85CL8QOkqIGHgAGtkeB2fBI3AcEcWOWTC3o5WiQQjnmyQDIJ3jKXuzhezcjqPqMrVWavnHbZAeP8J9gp-3-j4Q-FBp3avW5o3m1GcIOnXWG03lwnZ1RS+wN5eBf7voHh3v9-vS0YfwBVCVvANbHqeG7tvA+KvuMYG3ja96AYBT53quNCVgOvJDuwGzyFsOx7JAcztBg7LOIKsC8EII5IbR8BPviWwoHYmCYkI0BfBuGGSAcfiYY6b6sVRNF0aJ47npu+IzqJok2A8mQPnRcmPC4ik-spzhqdQQRaVQGmqbR+liPCxnAPMhpvNAvA0AgpDGqa6rmZgp7IOgWB4IQQLAGCarQpA7D-lQSjmLUHiCEUojtB4ihmKo8KVDoegGGWP7BcwoU5DY9hOC4UgdHIXi+AE8JDB6ERRDEKX7mlSRhWk2WZHl0XdBFJRlPAAD0HXwOAtYlWoQSmT5kJ+QF8I1Rl9TwJ6UWdDVAwJdUyWBSYE2WJl9UZLlbj5fwhXwP4AylWE5UmpVK3GGtdSpDNTWdC1vT9J13XOESQj-E4oAoLw4TwHkRB0Cm8AHDVA5aJR1HjOkOX9cMYhAA)

However, I'm not sure about `treshhold`. You did not provide it as a top level function but using it in nested object. Probably I did not understand something. Could you please leave a feedback?

P.S. Code is messy, I will refactor it and make it more clean

Comment: Thanks for all your work. Had laptop troubles this afternoon but I'm working through understanding all the nuances of the approach you've taken to see if I can replicate it. To clarify, the 'threshold' index is a derived index which makes its boolean rows by thresholding number rows from the length index at length 10. Later a further 'serialise' index makes its rows by toString-ing boolean rows from the threshold index (and also number rows from the length index). The two-step chain of indexes serialise=>threshold=>length - demonstrates a derived index from a derived index.

Comment: should I treat it `serialise=>threshold=>length` as a function composition? because `serialise` is not a function

Comment: In answer to your question, yes both threshold and serialise are maps of functions not functions. They define index(es) to draw from (each name in the map) and the transformation to perform (each function in the map). This contrasts to top-level indexes which operate directly on the items passed to the store, not the derived rows from some named index.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your expertise and time, @captain-yossarian. I may have arrived at a solution prompted by your approach. Referencing invalid index names or using incorrect arguments in index functions now raise compiler errors exactly as hoped. I wonder if you could take a look and see if there are tricks I've missed which could allow Typescript to 'derive' the generic types for `validate(indexConfig)` just from the indexConfig directly. Currently I have to provide both the config and its own type information e.g. `validate<typeof indexConfig, string>(indexConfig)` https://tsplay.dev/Nrvg1N

Comment: First thing which bothers me is that you have to use explicit generics `validate<typeof indexConfig, string>`. TS is able to infer literal object without explicit generics. I still don't understand the difference between `length` and `serialise`. Why `length` is top level function and `treshhold` is not since they are the functions of the same kind and should be composed. You should be able to call `validate` without any explicit generic and it should work

Comment: I think it worth to move `length` function to separate argument. Homogeneous dictionary is easy to read an understand whereas heterogeneous dictionary is a a mix

Comment: The length function isn't embedded in a map as it doesn't consume from any other named index (it defines an index, but doesn't consume from any). If I put it in a map, those property names would be meaningless. Top level functions handle original (untransformed) rows added directly to the store, not from any named index. Second level functions handle the (transformed) rows inserted in named indexes in the store and need the map names.

Comment: I have an implementation having the right constraints WITH an explicit type that matches the object, and it feels like it should be possible to DERIVE the type if I understood typescript inference better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238593/discussion-between-captain-yossarian-and-cefn).

Comment: Or maybe you mean having e.g. `[{length:indexFn}, {threshold:{length:deriveFn}}]` yes, I am happy with any sort of restructuring of the config object that doesn't create lines and lines of code and complexity, if it helps with the typing.